# Convert <netinet/in.h> protocols to names?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, ip

There is a long list of protocols defined in <netinet/in.h>:

```
/*
 * Protocols (RFC 1700)
 */
#define IPPROTO_IP              0               /* dummy for IP */
#if !defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE) || defined(_DARWIN_C_SOURCE)
#define IPPROTO_HOPOPTS 0               /* IP6 hop-by-hop options */
#endif  /* (!_POSIX_C_SOURCE || _DARWIN_C_SOURCE) */
#define IPPROTO_ICMP            1               /* control message protocol */
#if !defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE) || defined(_DARWIN_C_SOURCE)
#define IPPROTO_IGMP            2               /* group mgmt protocol */
#define IPPROTO_GGP             3               /* gateway^2 (deprecated) */
#define IPPROTO_IPV4            4               /* IPv4 encapsulation */
#define IPPROTO_IPIP            IPPROTO_IPV4    /* for compatibility */
#endif  /* (!_POSIX_C_SOURCE || _DARWIN_C_SOURCE) */
#define IPPROTO_TCP             6               /* tcp */
#if !defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE) || defined(_DARWIN_C_SOURCE)
#define IPPROTO_ST              7               /* Stream protocol II */

/* ... */
```

Is there a default function/call to translate protocols defined in <netinet/in.h> to names? Ideal to have chars[] in return:

```
ipproto2str(IPPROTO_ICMP): "Control Message Protocol (ICMP)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`getprotobynumber()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getprotoent.3.html).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(void) {
  struct protoent *p = getprotobynumber(IPPROTO_ICMP);
  if (p) {
    printf("IPPROTO_ICMP (%d) = %s\n", p->p_proto, p->p_name);
  } else {
    puts("Couldn't find IPPROTO_ICMP");
  }
}
```

Comment: The authoritative link:  https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getprotobynumber.html